# Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK + Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal = Error

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

Since the "standard" Api to access VS's debugger seems to be extremely limited, I have manually added a reference to *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal.dll* while using the VS-SDK nuget. This compiles and runs when I use this code:

```
IDebuggerInternal debugger = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IDebuggerInternal;
var session = debugger?.CurrentSession;
```

but when I change it to use the explicit type *IDebugSession3*

```
IDebuggerInternal debugger = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IDebuggerInternal;           
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.IDebugSession3 session = debugger?.CurrentSession;
```

I receive an error:

> error CS0433: The type 'IDebugSession3' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop, Version=8.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Sadly, *var* cannot be used in all cases to circumvent compiler errors, e.g. when enums are needed.
So, my question is: (How) Can the internal debugger-Api be used together with the VS-SDK nuget?

BTW: A while ago, I had a similar issue with *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Publish.dll* and the type *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Publish.Framework.PublishManager* which I didn't investigate furtherly.

Comment: Hi frank, where does the IDebuggerInternal come from? It seems an custom interface.

Comment: The assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal.dll contains the type IDebuggerInternal, IDebuggerInternal110, IDebuggerInternal120 and many more in the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal